# Deleted the migrations folder accidently so I dropped all my tables in database but still not working

Tags: python, django

I deleted my migrations folder accidently so to make things work again I dropped all tables in my database as well. But now even tho python manage.py makemigrations is working, python manage.py migrate still says 'No migrations to apply' why?

Comment: There is table that tracks applied migrations.  That might be doing this.  Wouldnt be surprised if the given answer empties it.

Comment: Can you post your answer? This resolved my problem.

Comment: Sure. Can you remind what the table name is?  I did this last year so forgot by now.

Comment: django_migrations i believe

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands :

1. `py manage.py migrate  zero`
2. `py manage.py makemigrations`
3. `py manage.py migrate`